# how do i stick a html tag on the right side?

Tags: html, css

My goal is simple, stick the p tag to the right side of the custom css card, to make it stick to the left it is pretty straightforward.

```
custom-text {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

To better illustrate this[image]

The question is how do I make the $100 dollars always stick to the right?
and let say the value of the dollars change to $5, how to make it always on the right?

I can just use

```
custom-text-right {
    margin-left: 450px;
}
```

but this solution doesn't scale to different value (Im using bootstrap just for your information)

HTML part:

```
<h4>Price: <span class="dollar">$3.15</span></h4>
```

Comment: `float: right`?

Comment: please show your html too - see [MCVE]

Comment: why is this question marked as duplicate? he/she doesn't ask about flexbox.

Comment: @OlivierKrull — They ask about aligning left and right. The duplicate question has just already realized that flexbox is the tool to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do that using flexbox, with `justify-content: space-between;`

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #000;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <span>Price:</span>
  <span> $100</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution is not flexible, what if there are multiple price and dollar value? I tried it and it doesn't work on multiple span

Comment: It will just position it on the same row.

Comment: @sinusGob see updated answer

Comment: Alright thanks, but it still doesn't work. Take a look at the jsfiddle. The reason Why I wrote the code differently, because there is an input group https://jsfiddle.net/abqesbzf/2/

Comment: here is your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6ycd1g0/)

Comment: Amazing! thanks alot for taking your time to help. God bless you!

Answer (score -1):

You can use **float: right** or **text-align:right**

Comment: All else being equal, `float: right` would cause the price to drop down to the next line and `text-align: right` would either have no effect or align both bits of content to the right. It's possible to use both of these to get the desired effect, but not without additional work, so the answer isn't complete.